# EF: how do i model 1:1 without db referential integrity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Consider the following tables:

```
Base, Primary key: Id
Extension, Primary key: Id
```

The primary key in the "Extension" table has the same value as the primary key in the "Base" table. I want to model this in the edmx as such:

**Base can have 0..1 (Zero or One) instances of Extension.**

Extension can have 1 (One) instance of Base. Use Extension.Base to access the Base instance.

When I try to specify the mapping details for this association, I get an error such as this:

> "Error 3021: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line xx:Each of
>   the following columns in table Base is mapped to multiple conceptual
>   side properties: Base.ID is mapped to "

How can I model a 1:0..1 relationship which is not backed by a database relationship? I basically want a relationship so I can query my read-model using Linq.

Comment: Entity framework is strongly dependent on database level so to make this work you should add relation to the database. It should be possible to achieve this in EF without database changes but it works only sometimes - especially if you try to modify data as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading you correct then your doing something similar to a problem I had to resolve to too long back in a messeging system.

Basically, I created an intermediate table, with 2 columns in, both ints, 1 held the id from one table, and the other the id from another table, that then allowed me to bridge the two together.

so EG:

```
--------------------------
| Base ID | Extension ID |
--------------------------
```

I did have to manage the table manually however, so a little extra work, but it did the trick.

Maybe not the exact schema you need, but I think the intermediate table whatever your scheme is a sensible way to look at addressing your needs.

Comment: This worked without referential integrity in the database? And how did you model this in the edmx?

Comment: Yep, certainly did.  I created the table by hand in my DB, and I added the FK links myself, then I just pointed EF at it, and told it to create the model. SInce there's nothing special about the design, you should have no problem doing it code first , or model first.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your mode classes like following for 1:1 relationship :-

**Base Class**

```
public class Base
{
    public int BaseID;
    public int ExtentionID;
    public virtual Extention Extension { get; set; }
}
```

**Extention Class**

```
public class Extention
{
    public int ExtentionID;
    public int BaseID;
    public Base Base { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Were are generating the POCO's from the edmx using a t4 template, so I am more interested in how this would look in your edmx file.

Comment: ohh k...I thought you might like this one. Since it really is a great way of dealing with tables and models. Anyways sorry for the irrelevant answer on my part.

Comment: I'm not saying your post is irrelevant, I am just saying its very short :-)